# How can I get SSMS to persist my custom keyboard shortcut?

Tags: ssms

I'm on Windows 10, and SQL Server 2012 Developer, with SSMSBoost installed.

I want to assign `Ctrl + K, Ctrl + F` to do SSMSBoost's Format command.  I do it through the normal `Tools → Options → Environment → Keyboard → Keyboard` method, and the shortcut works.  But when I quit SSMS and reopen it, the shortcut setting is gone.  Doing Exports of the settings in each state and diffing the two files also reflects this difference.

**How do I get it to remember the shortcut between runs?**

---

**EDIT:**

No added keyboard shortcuts stick at all, for any command.  Oddly enough, *deleted* ones *do* stick.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, but I'm using SSMS for 2016 and the latest SSMSBoost for that version of SSMS.  I was able to add a keyboard shortcut for Ctrl-K, Ctrl-F and assign it to SSMSBoost.Format (making sure it was to be used in Sql Editor).  I tested the shortcut and it worked.  I then got completely out of SSMS and brought it back up - the shortcut still worked for me - not sure if a later version of SSMS and SSMSBoost might fix your problem.

Comment: Of course that doesn't demand that you update SQL Server itself......  should I worry that the download page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms has a number of failings of English grammar?  Either it's been put there by hackers????? or Microsoft programmers are losing the ability to communicate with human beings...  I blame the emoji; we should have seen this coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further investigation, this seems to be a bug in SSMSBoost, at least on the current version (3.0.6397).  Uninstalling it makes the keyboard shortcuts work normally.  :(